# Laravel with Elasticbeanstalk: All the routes return 404 except for '/' route

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to deploy really simple laravel 7 application to Elasticbeanstalk, I did everything [just like this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc&t=1366s) 
Everything is going fine until I click on any other route except for the `/` route.

http://laravelbooksystem-env.eba-vmyh6fvn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/      (working)

http://laravelbooksystem-env.eba-vmyh6fvn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/experts  (Not working)

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/experts', 'ExpertsController@index');

Route::get('/experts/{id}/show', 'ExpertsController@show');

Route::get('/experts/{id}/book', 'AppointmentsController@display');


Route::post('/appointment/{id}', 'AppointmentsController@store');
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.ebextentions

```
container_commands:
    01_clear_config:
        command: "php artisan config:clear"
    02_clear_cache:
        command: "php artisan cache:clear"    
    03_build_db:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    04_seed:
        command: "php artisan db:seed --force"
```

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: Share your routes & blade files so we can help you

Comment: @Makdous, sure give me a mnt.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this and fixed the issue by following directions posted by niallD here:
[Any AWS EB Laravel route getting 404 Not Found nginx/1.16.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640771/any-aws-eb-laravel-route-getting-404-not-found-nginx-1-16-1)