# Laravel Route not working after I deployed in Beanstalk AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I follow different article and tutorial video for deploying **Laravel 5.6** in AWS Beanstalk. All the config are done; adding database (mysql) and upload zip file. Problem is, it shows 404 error in every route **except "/" i.e root** (aka website link). It shows ***first page or root page*** but does not show other **route pages**.

Error Screenshots

1. [Root Page (print env)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov2yE.png)
2. [Other route like (api)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQJ93.png)

Instruction and tutorial I followed:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um1zQKPVFfU (EC2 Instance)
- https://medium.com/sk-geek/deploy-laravel-app-to-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-ec2-6cdff6689347
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html (official tutorial)
- https://www.infinitypp.com/amazon-aws/how-to-hose-laravel-application-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ (EB CLI)
- https://blog.memcachier.com/2019/01/28/laravel-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/

**Edit: Solution for the problem is in this link**

- [Any AWS EB Laravel route getting 404 Not Found nginx/1.16.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640771/any-aws-eb-laravel-route-getting-404-not-found-nginx-1-16-1/61758933#61758933)
- [Any AWS EB Laravel route getting 404 Not Found nginx/1.16.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640771/any-aws-eb-laravel-route-getting-404-not-found-nginx-1-16-1/61758933#61740949)
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx

**Or change proxy server from "Nginx" to "Apache" in Environment Configuration**

Comment: Any update on this?? I have the same problem

Comment: hi, i tried this solution and it worked for me. good luck. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758933/3964127

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create a folder structure like this in your root folder:
   **.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf**
2. Paste this code in the "laravel.conf" file:

.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named: **laravel.conf** in this directory: **.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk**

Copy paste this content inside laravel.conf file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```