# elasticbeanstalk get 404 when I use nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the same issue as [404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640771/any-aws-eb-laravel-route-getting-404-not-found-nginx-1-16-1)
and the answers is correct and when I add

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
}
```

The problem is solved.
How can I do such a thing in .ebextensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize nginx on **Amazon Linux 2** you should use `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not  .ebextensions`. The` .ebextensions` were used for Amazon Linux 1.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) provide an example of how to add **configuration options** to nginx:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .platform
|   `-- nginx
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- myconf.conf
```

Comment: I want to change php.conf
in    cd /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk

Comment: can I do that
by .platform/nginx/conf.d/php.conf?

Comment: @yasinlachini You can try. You can even fully overwrite entire nginx settings as explained in the docs if this is need. If this does not work, you can update your question with more details to help better identify the solution.

Comment: @yasinlachini [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978311/248823) in the questions you've liked also shows how to overwrite entire nginx settings on AL2.

Comment: the problem solved after I add .platform/nginx/conf.d/php.conf

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "add .platform/nginx/conf.d/php.conf"? I've been struggling with the same problem and have not found a way to have this line added automatically via deployment (and I really don't want to override the entire configuration just to change one thing).

Comment: @MikelG I would suggest making new question with details specific to your issue and use case.

Comment: My question is exactly this... How can I add the configuration line automatically during deployment? I have tried what you suggested every which way and it does not work. When I vim into PHP.conf and add the lines manually, it works fine. Making another question would be a duplicate.

Comment: In hopes of getting more attention, I've followed your suggestion @Marcin.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940725/elastic-beanstalk-nginx-extending-configuration