# AWS error 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 in elastic beanstalk with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx

I got this error when I deploy the Laravel project to AWS

```
404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0
```

I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640771/any-aws-eb-laravel-route-getting-404-not-found-nginx-1-16-1) and create this path in main dir of the project but still the error there!

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf
```

inside `laravel.conf`:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  gzip_static on;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Goto Configurations on the left pane
2. Select software edit
3. under root document write /public
4. if you got 404 again change Nginx to apache

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing from Nginx to Apache did it for me, after setting the document root to /public.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the document root folder is pointed to the public folder, not the installation root folder

Comment: Can you please explain more I didn't get you! ( you mean move the path that I create to public folder ?)

Comment: in nginx you specify the root folder, make sure it's pointing to the public folder inside laravel installation

Comment: that's mean move laravel.conf to public folder ?